# Microservices architecture - Spring boot - Gateway

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, gateway

I'm developing a back-end with microservices architecture. I'm new about that architecture and for now I have developed 3 microservices (RESTful web services, with Spring Boot) each in a container.
I want to implement OAuth2 and JWT Rest Protection and a gateway.
Is it correct to implement a gateway with Authorization Server and Resource Server?
Am I doing something wrong about the architecture?

Thanks for the replies

Answer (score 2):

As per the standard, should not mix gateway with authorization because both the purposes are different.

**Gateway**

Gateway can be differentiated in two ways - Internal and External. Purpose of gateway is to route the call from external or internal to the protected resource.

**Authorization Server**

Authorization server comes into the picture for identity access management. All the request coming from external or internal via gateway should be authenticated or authorized  before routing call to the protected resource with JWT or access token etc.

https://medium.com/swlh/authentication-and-authorization-in-microservices-how-to-implement-it-5d01ed683d6f

Answer (score 1):

Authentication and Authorization - There should be a separate service that authentication the user (like supporting OAuth0 type of protocol and providing JWT Token). Your frontend should call API Gateway.

Now question comes at what granular level you are maintaining permissions - Only small set of roles or granular level of permission set. Now API Gateway should communicate with Authorization server with JWT and get the set of roles and permission. Based on the same, API gateway should forward or block the call to Microservice.

Even if you have small set of roles and JWT can be extracted and validated by Gateway but avoid to keep the same at Gateway as there are chances that you have to extract the functionality to some other service in near future.